# Python docker image fails because of missing shell / bash in the image

Tags: python, bash, docker, kubernetes

I have the following Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM python:3-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -qr requirements.txt
COPY target-watch.py .
CMD ["python3", "./target-watch.py"]
```

If I deploy this to a Kubernetes cluster the build went fine, but I got an error from the Kubernetes logs. To verfiy my image I run the following command:

```sh
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash  docker-conveyor.xxx.com/myorg/my_cron_jobs:2021.12.08_03.51_abcdef
```

Which gives me this response:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

How can this be fixed? I assume a shell is missing in my image. How do i have to change my Dockerfile to make it work without any errors?

Comment: You can either install `bash` in the image, or choose a command that is already installed (like `python3`?) to verify the image.

Comment: You shouldn't usually need a `--entrypoint` option (if you do, try changing `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` for simpler syntax).  What do you get if you just `docker run` the image?  For interactive debugging, does it work to `docker run --rm -it .../my_cron_jobs:... sh` using `sh` instead of `bash` as the shell?

Comment: `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container image doesn't have bash so you should use /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash.

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/sh  docker-conveyor.xxx.com/myorg/my_cron_jobs:2021.12.08_03.51_abcdef
```

Alpine docker image doesn't have bash installed by default. You will need to add the following commands to get bash:

```
RUN apk update && apk add bash
```

If you're using Alpine 3.3+ then you can just do

```
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
```

Comment: Alpine Linux use BusyBox. You can use `sh` or `ash`.